# Chrome Packages app with JSRender and JSviews

Tags: google-chrome, jsrender, jsviews, google-chrome-app

Can I use JSRender and JSViews libraries(http://www.jsviews.com/) in building Chrome Packaged App? Does it violate the CSP policy?

This library syntax uses "script" tag to identify template definition in the HTML file...following is an example of it

> ```
> <script id="theTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender"> <div>    <em>Name:</em>
> {{:name}}    {{if showNickname && nickname}}
>   (Goes by <em>{{:nickname}}</em>)    {{/if}} </div> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe JsRender and JsViews are currently CSP compliant, because template compilation uses `new Function()`. However pre-compilation should be very easy. See [jsrender/issues/30](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/30) and [jsrender/issues/164](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/164) . A precompile tool is planned for V1 or V1.1.

In fact you can already do your own precompiling simply by writing:

`var myTemplate = $.templates("myTemplateMarkupString");`

As to the script tag, no, you don't have to use that approach to declaring templates. As shown above, you can compile from strings or precompile. See http://www.jsviews.com/#compiletmpl for more details and examples.